# Having an issue with CoverterParameter Binding in silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

I am having an issue with the xaml parser not liking my binding statement but i cannot see anything wrong with the statement.

> Invalid attribute value {Binding VehicleSpeed, ConverterParameter={Binding InMiles}, Converter={StaticResource SpeedConverter}, Mode=TwoWay} for property DataMemberBinding

VehicleSpeed and InMiles are parameters on the class that I have in the DataContext property of the xaml top level grid of the xaml document.

This statement used to work without the ConverterParameter by it is now complaining after added the second binding to the "bool InMiles" that i am trying to pass through to the ValueConverter.

If anyone can see anything wrong with this line please let me know.

Comment: The design is a little perplexing.  Either the `InMiles` property indicates "Please display speed in Miles per hour" or it means "the current value in the `VehicleleSpeed` prorperty is in units of Miles per hour".  Which is it?.  Also what is the data type of `VehicleSpeed` and what type of control are you binding to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind the converter parameter, because it is not a dependency property of the binding object.

Instead you can pass the whole data item to the converter and use its **VehicleSpeed** and **InMiles** properties in the Convert() method.

Comment: Yep. It will be tricky with TwoWay data binding. May be a custom CellTemplate should be used for this column.

Comment: How would you pass the whole data item to the converter? Is this in the primary binding?

Comment: Leave the binding path empty or '.'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use DataBinding for a Converter Parameter.  I think instead you would need to pass in the bound object and access the properties from there.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   Instead you can pass the whole data item to the converter and use its VehicleSpeed and InMiles properties in the Convert() method.
>   Blockquote

Yes, it is could be right approach, but sometime you have object which is not changed, only properties of that object changed (via INotifyPropertyChanged).

So if you do like this

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding Model}>
 <MyControl SomeProperty={Binging, converter={staticResourse ConverterWhichTakesViewModel}/>
</Grid>
```

changes in properties of the Model will not have impact on MyControl, because Model is not changed.

So it would be nice to have do something like this:

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding Model}>
     <MyControl SomeProperty={Binging Model.MyProperty, converter={staticResourse ConverterWhichTakesViewModel}, ConverterParameter ={Bindging}/>
 </Grid>
```

But it doesn't work...-(((. Exception: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Any thought on this?